# How to loop in files using imacros

Tags: imacros

I am trying to use imacros to upload videos to let's say youtube.

Currently it looks like this -

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 
RECORDER=FX 
TAB T=1 
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
URL GOTO=youtube 
UPLOAD URL TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Upload<SP>new<SP>videos 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:upload_form_basic ATTR=ID:file_basic CONTENT=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\UPLOAD<SP>Test\({{!LOOP}}).mp4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:video_keywords  CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:terms CONTENT=YES 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:upload_form_basic ATTR=ID:upload_submit
WAIT SECONDS=20
```

The problem i am facing here is -

I have let's say 50 videos saved in this folder with random names all .mp4 format.
I want imacros to wait stipulated time frame before it comes back to this loop and pick the NEXT file in the same folder. I am unable to do that.

Can anyone help me how should i make imacros pick the next file in the second loop. ?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: If **random** filenames aren’t principal for you, (1) rename your files by order (i.e. 1.mp4, 2 .mp4, etc.), (2) indicate `{{!LOOP}}.mp4` as a filename in the macro and (3) play it in loop mode.

Answer (score 0):

Hi. Simply create a file list then use it in the loop.

1. Move **createlist.bat** on your video folder and run once.

   ```
   @echo off
   dir /b /s *.mp4 > %USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\list.txt
   ```

   By the way it will create with all subdirectories (!) on your video folder. If you want non recursive way use it:

   ```
   @echo off
   del %USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\list.txt
   for /f "usebackq TOKENS=*" %%i in (`dir /b *.mp4`) do (echo %%~fnxi) >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\list.txt
   ```
2. Now use the list.txt as datasource. The list.txt has only 1 column. You can call each line using {{!COL1}}}. For more info [Form Filling.](http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling)

   ```
   SET !DATASOURCE list.txt
   SET !LOOP 1
   SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
   '.....
   '..... URL GOTO www.yoursite...
   '..... Fill here according to your site
   '.....
   '.....
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:upload_form_basic ATTR=ID:file_basic CONTENT={{!COL1}})
   '.....
   '.....
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The `{{!LOOP}}.FILE EXTENSION` works for me with sequential numbers within my file names.